# Problem in downloading csv file, I have create it but not able to download in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void LnkExcelDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Student_Details where 1=2", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            string csv = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {                    
                csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
            }

            csv += "\r\n";

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {                       
                    csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                }

                csv += "\r\n";
            }

            byte[] data = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(csv);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.csv");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(data);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); 
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }        
}
```

Comment: What is `dt`? Has it been declared?

Comment: Its a Datatable